# Mysql case condition with LIKE

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use case condition in select statement but it is not giving correct results, however when i use that condition in where clause it is working.

The following query is working :

```
SELECT  'Postpaid' AS 'Description',
SUM(ROUND(duration/60,3))  AS Minutes
FROM cdr WHERE typeofcall IN ('0800 Voice Incoming Off Peak','0800 Voice Incoming Peak')
AND
(callingparty LIKE '67%' OR callingparty  LIKE '28%' OR callingparty  LIKE '38%'
OR callingparty  LIKE '48%' OR callingparty  LIKE '58%'
OR callingparty  LIKE '78%' OR callingparty  LIKE '88%')   
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(timeofcall,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') >='2019-05-01'
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(timeofcall,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') <='2019-05-31'
AND charge >0



Description  Minutes  
-----------  ---------

Postpaid       198.351
```

But my requirement is this query which is not giving results:

```
SELECT  'Postpaid' AS 'Description',
(CASE WHEN callingparty LIKE '67%' OR callingparty  LIKE '28%' OR callingparty  LIKE '38%'
OR callingparty  LIKE '48%' OR callingparty  LIKE '58%'
OR callingparty  LIKE '78%' OR callingparty  LIKE '88%' 
  THEN SUM(ROUND(duration/60,3)) ELSE 0 END )AS Minutes
FROM cdr WHERE typeofcall IN ('0800 Voice Incoming Off Peak','0800 Voice Incoming Peak')
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(timeofcall,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') >='2019-05-01'
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(timeofcall,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') <='2019-05-31'
AND charge >0

Description  Minutes  
-----------  ---------

Postpaid         0.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the case and put the sum and the round outside:

```
SELECT  'Postpaid' AS 'Description',
round(sum((CASE WHEN callingparty LIKE '67%' OR callingparty  LIKE '28%' OR callingparty  LIKE '38%'
OR callingparty  LIKE '48%' OR callingparty  LIKE '58%'
OR callingparty  LIKE '78%' OR callingparty  LIKE '88%' 
  THEN duration/60 ELSE 0 END) ),3) AS Minutes
FROM cdr WHERE typeofcall IN ('0800 Voice Incoming Off Peak','0800 Voice Incoming Peak')
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(timeofcall,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') >='2019-05-01'
AND FROM_UNIXTIME(timeofcall,'%Y-%m-%d %h:%i:%s') <='2019-05-31'
AND charge >0
```

You need to sum the values in case your condition is meet but if not, you need to sum 0